# Word for a dog searching?

Tags: single-word-request

What is the verb for a dog searching or sniffing for something? Is *spüren* fitting? After all, that is what a Spürhund does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, a Spürhund does not *spüren* (*to feel*) but **aufspüren** (*to scent*, *to track down*) someone or something. As Emanuel correctly pointed out in comments, *aufspüren* means that the dog eventually found what he was searching.

The word *sniffing* is translated as *schnüffeln*. It means to breathe in to detect a smell and to discover something. (*Schnüffeln* is also figuratively used, as in English, for people who are *sniffing around*).

Dogs also *schnuppern* (*to smell*) something, that means he puts his nose near something to identify its smell.

Or you can simply use **suchen** (*to search*). This is the most common word when you take your dog for a walk and you play with him (throwing a ball, for instance). This word is also used for *Spürhunde*. They're also called *Suchhunde* anyway.

For the sake of completeness, if the dog found a trace, you can use *wittern* or *riechen*. Or the phrase *eine Fährte aufnehmen*.

Comment: I think I'll go with *wittern*. I'm trying to describe [this](http://www.moma.org/collection_images/resized/431/w500h420/CRI_81431.jpg), btw.

Comment: @MadTux This is kind of abstract. If you're writing a detailed description, you can even use all of the words. If it's a single sentence, it really depends on your actual sentence.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that "aufspüren" is rather perfective, meaning that it does imply finding the item. The mere attempt at finding is not "aufspüren".

Comment: Witterung aufnehmen

Answer (score 3):

Ich habe mal ein bisschen bei Wikipedia durch den [Jägerjargon](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%A4gersprache) gescrollt. Dabei habe ich folgende Begriffe gefunden:

> Nachsuche: bezeichnet den Hund, der geschossenes Wild sucht und stellt (wird in mehreren Einträgen benutzt)
>
> winden: mit dem Geruchssinn etwas wahrnehmen, riechen; beim Wild und beim Hund gebraucht (Zitat von Wikipedia)

Dann gibt es da noch den Begriff **Quersuche**, der beschreibt, dass der Hund in einem großen Umkreis sucht.
Und nicht zuletzt lautet auch ein gängiges Kommando für Hunde

> Such!

Daher würde ich sagen, das allgemeine Wort für was der Hund macht ist schlicht und einfach:

> suchen